# GLTF Model not rendered in scene A-FRAME

Tags: reactjs, aframe, webvr

So I'm still new using A-Frame now I need to add a GLTF object in my A-FRAME Scene. I think I already add it properly but it still not shows up. Here is my Code

```
import React from 'react';
import AFRAME from 'aframe';


    class Forest extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div  >
                    <a-scene>
                        <a-assets>
                            <img id="boxTexture" src="https://i.imgur.com/mYmmbrp.jpg" />
                            <img id="skyTexture"
                                src={require('../assets/sechelt.jpg')} />
                            <img id="groundTexture" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/a-painter/images/floor.jpg"></img>
                            <a-asset-item id="homer" src={require('../assets/scene.gltf')} ></a-asset-item>
                        </a-assets>
                        <a-box onClick={() => alert("Oke")} src="#boxTexture" position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2"
                            animation="property: object3D.position.y; to: 2.2; dir: alternate; dur: 2000; loop: true"></a-box>
                        <a-plane src="#groundTexture" rotation="-90 0 0" width="30" height="30"
                            repeat="10 10"></a-plane>
    
                        <a-gltf-model src="#homer" position="0 0 0" scale="2 2 2" ></a-gltf-model>
                        <a-link href="index.html" title="Visit Booth" image="#homeThumbnail"></a-link>
    
                        <a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>
                        <a-light type="ambient" color="#445451"></a-light>
                        <a-light type="point" intensity="2" position="2 4 4"></a-light>
                        <a-camera>
                            <a-cursor></a-cursor>
                        </a-camera>
                    </a-scene>
                </div>
    
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default Forest;
```

From this documentation https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/primitives/a-gltf-model.html I think I already followed the example. Is there an extra step to render the 3d object?
Here is the Inspect screenshot, my 3d object is not loaded it should show the Simpsons house
[image]

Comment: There's no extra step, could you share a link to the model and/or a codesandbox of your setup? Sometimes the model might just have a weird origin or scaling.

Comment: Did it work with a string path for src instead of require?

Comment: oke so after I put my 3d model inside the public folder it works now. I don't know if that's the problem or no because my ground texture is can be loaded without any Issue.